# Having Trouble Creating a MongoDB Database with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to create a database in MongoDB using npm Mongoose and Robomongo as my GUI. I followed the MongoDB Quickstart Docs at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html, but the database does not appear in Robomongo. Basically, I'm just trying to have the database "appear" in Robomongo when I run the server.js file through Node.

When I enter the code below, from the MongoDB Quickstart Docs, there is NO database created/appearing in Robomongo.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});

var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
```

But...
When I add in the employeeid field (below) into the Schema, then the database appears in Robomongo.
Can somebody explain the difference between these two pieces of code? Why one works and the other doesn't?

```
var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    employeeid:{
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        required: true

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `employeeid` has an index on it (from `unique`, at least -- probably `required` too? not 100% sure on how mongoose handles required fields). Mongoose will automatically create collections which have indexes defined on them.

Otherwise, the collection will be created after you "do" something with it (like creating a `Kitten` and using `.save()` wiht it).

Comment: Omg you're right that worked! I used the .save() function and it finally created the collection in the database with just the name attribute. It didn't appear until I saved into it. I have seriously spent the last 3 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem - it's a bit unintuitive, but it's how mongodb handles it as well. For example, when using the mongo command line, you can switch to a database, have it selected, but that database won't exist until you insert -- despite the fact that you have it selected. There's some additional reading [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18313) in the mongodb issue tracker (see the comments at the bottom).